# Possible to create more than one Ikev2 VPN using network extension in Mac OSX?

Tags: ios, macos, networkextension

My requirement is to create multiple tunnels using network extensions.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to create more than one out-of-the-box available (**IKEv2** / **IPsec**) VPN protocol configurations in a single app.

---

If you want to create multiple VPN configurations, you will need to use [NETunnelProviderManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/netunnelprovidermanager) with your custom **VPN** protocol (which you can implement as **IKEv2**, but it will require much more work than just using already available protocols in [NEVPNManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager)).

---

Some information where to start could be found [here](https://kean.blog/post/vpn-configuration-manager).